# Position: fixed inside display: table bug

Tags: css

I've come across a really frustrating issue. I'm working to create a menu drawer that is inside a `<ul>`. When the nested `<div>` inside the table is `display: {fixed,absolute}`, a whitespace placeholder shows up where another table cell would be. I can't understand why or how to get around it.

CodePen of the code is here: http://codepen.io/quicksnap/pen/gsHrb and you can toggle the topmost class to see what I'm talking about.

Appreciate any insight on why or how to retain this markup structure and get it to display fixed/absolute without altering the parent table display.

Markup:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href=""><span>Lorem</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><span>Lorem</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><span>Lorem</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><span>Lorem</span></a>
  </li>
  <div class="fixed"/>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/*
 Why does the display: table show an empty placeholder for
 an element inside that is position: fixed/absolute?
*/

/* Comment out/remove !important to see bug */
.fixed { display: none !important; }

.fixed { 
  display: block;
  position: fixed; top: 60px; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100px;
  background: salmon;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
}

ul > li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know if this is a bug or expected behavior (I have not researched it), as it appears to do the same on a normal `table` element. However, it apparently has to do with the `table-layout: fixed` property being set. I am guessing that is because the `table-layout: fixed` calculates its size based on the number of columns, and it appears to be counting that as a "[column element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#fixed-table-layout)" upon page render, apparently before even recognizing that the css `position: fixed` pulls it out of flow. The `display: none` causes the element to not count (as one would expect) for column purposes.

Your issue seems to resolve by having the `table` (in your case `ul`) be `table-layout: auto` and then setting the cells (your `li`) to the appropriate width (25% in your case) unless they all have exactly the same width text.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNhrH/9/) for an illustration of all these things happening on a normal `table` element.

As a side note, a naked `div` in a `ul` is not valid html structure (the `ul` should only have `li` elements as direct children).

Comment: Didn't realize that it's not valid HTML! I may try an experiment with that knowledge.

Comment: Also, the `table-layout: fixed` is necessary in my situation. Or at least strongly preferred opposed to hard-coding or Javascripting widths per-element.

Comment: @Dan: The best thing would be to pull the fixed element out of the `table` structure, since being `position: fixed` it can theoretically be defined anywhere in the code.

Comment: I agree, but I have a peculiar setup where nested `ul`s would need their own fixed drawers to display on top of the `li`s underneath. Basically, I need something to display between nested elements. Even with z-index, I cannot get a "drawer" to display between nested elements in a table structure unless the element is within markup. I should probably make a new question to see if there's a good way of going about this.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of your div / fixed class? You can nest another ul or list however and put the "fixed" class on that. If you add height 100% then the whole background is the salmon color you have.

Comment: The `fixed` element is meant to act as a menu drawer that displays below any (possibly nested) UL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `display: table` will render children elements in the fixed layout regardless if their display is set to `absolute` or `fixed`--If they're displaying as a block element, the cell gets drawn.

This is a simplified version of the "bug":

http://codepen.io/quicksnap/pen/xuDwG ( notice the extra space to the right of the Lorem items )

When using `table-caption` for an `li` and then nesting in a fixed or absolute element, it seems to escape the element from being drawn as a cell.

Here is an example of what I was looking for: http://codepen.io/quicksnap/pen/noBvm

Thanks ScottS for pointing out my invalid HTML--it clued me into why it works like this, though I still don't understand why the table is drawing a cell space for an element that isn't `table-cell` and positioned absolute/fixed.